# error when starting mysql with brew

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, homebrew

I'm starting to learn PHP Laravel, I reached the valet installation and came to the point where I need to install mysql with brew with this command

```
brew install mysql
```

the mysql installation is done successfully, However when I run the command

```
brew services start mysql
```

I get this error that I couldn't find a solution for

```
 sh: 1: list: not found
 Error: Failure while executing:  load -w 
 /home/chemseddinez/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

**PS: I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Answer (score 0):

`brew services` only works with macOS' launchctl manager. You can start mysql manually using `$(brew --prefix)/bin/mysql.server`.

Or you can just install `apt-get install mysql-server` and launch it as daemon via `systemctl start mysql`.